# Adding List of last 18 Months to Drop Down in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have to add last 18 months to a drop down in asp.net C#.

I have written the logic to get last 18 months as follows.,

```
    List<string> dateList= new List<string>();
    private List<string> GetDateDropDownList(DropDown pDropDown)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
            var month = dt.ToString("MMMM");
            var year = dt.Year;
             dateList.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", month, year));
         }
         return dateList;
       }
```

now I need to add this list to drop down. I am trying but it is not working. How can I add it to the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what others have said, you just bind your function to it.

However, you have a little issue in your code. You create your `dateList` outside of your actual method, instead of inside of it. You also do not need to pass a dropdown list into the method.

So your updated method should be:

```
private List<string> GetDateDropDownList()// get rid of parameter
{
  List<string> dateList= new List<string>(); // inside method
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
        var month = dt.ToString("MMMM");
        var year = dt.Year;
         dateList.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", month, year));
     }
     return dateList;
   }
```

And you bind your dropdown direct to the method

```
myDropdown.DataSource = GetDateDropDownList();
myDropdown.DataBind();
```

Alternatively, with your original method you can do the following - notice it's now a void and does not return a list.

```
 private void GetDateDropDownList(DropDown pDropDown)
    {
       List<string> dateList= new List<string>();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
            var month = dt.ToString("MMMM");
            var year = dt.Year;
             dateList.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", month, year));
         }
         pDropDown.DataSource = dateList;
         pDropDown.DataBind()
       }
```

And you would simply pass in your dropdown list

```
GetDateDropDownList(myDropdownList);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing in your method is building a list.  You never add it to the drop down.  Like this...

```
pDropDown.DataSource = dateList;
pDropDown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently building a list of strings, but in order to make it visible within your dropdown, you'll need to specifically set the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.datasource(v=vs.90).aspx) property and then call [`DataBind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.databind(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply the changes:

```
// This sets your data
pDropDown.DataSource = dateList;
// This actually binds the current data to the DropDownList control
pDropDown.DataBind();
```

Additionally, you likely won't need to be returning any values from this method (unless you need them for some other reason) and could consider making it return `void`:

```
private void SetDatesForDropDown(DropDown pDropDown, int monthsBack = 18)
{
    List<string> dateList= new List<string>();
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 1; i <= monthsBack; i++)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
        dateList.Add(dt.ToString("MMMM-yyyy"));
    }

    pDropDown.DataSource = dateList;
    pDropDown.DataBind();
}
```

Or simply removing the `DropDown` parameter and using the results of the method to set your `DataSource`:

```
private void GetDateRanges(int monthsBack = 18)
{
    List<string> dateList= new List<string>();
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 1; i <= monthsBack; i++)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
        dateList.Add(dt.ToString("MMMM-yyyy"));
    }

    return dateList;
}
```

along with:

```
YourDropDown.DataSource = GetDateRanges();
YourDropDown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing this, below is one such way. 
Just remember to bind it to a dropdownlist.

**EDITED - Getting the Selected Value**

**Frontend - ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnLoad="DropDownList1_Load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Codebehind - C#**

```
//Populate the DropDownList
protected void DropDownList1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        // Instantiate your DropDownList
        DropDownList drpList = (DropDownList)sender;

        List<string> dateList = new List<string>();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
            var month = dt.ToString("MMMM");
            var year = dt.Year;
            dateList.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", month, year));
        }

        // Bind resulting list to the DropDownList
        drpList.DataSource = dateList;
        drpList.DataBind();
   }
}

//Get the Selected Value on change
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // assign the selected item value to a variable 
        string value = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
    }
```

---

Comment: @Kevin...Thank you. This event method worked out for me.

Comment: @Kevin...How Can I select the List Item Value from the drop down list? I want to store the selected date from the drop down list in a variable.

Comment: I've edited my answer with how to select the list item value. Alternatively you can simply call `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`if you want to get the value from a method other than _SelectedIndexChanged_

Comment: Thank you  Kevin Bonkewitzz